# Getting correct RSS Feed img

Tags: c#, asp.net, image, rss

I am using a syndication feed to extract get an RSS feed along with it's corresponding image. However getting the RSS image is proving to be tricky because every RSS feed seems to have the images defined on different levels in the feed.

For example some RSS feeds have the corresponding image in the (thumbnail) element or within the (content) element, or (content:encoded) element etc...

This is fine, since the image is usually in the syndication feed item summary, or one of the extension elements (for encoded content). However... Sometimes the first image found is the image for the feed item, while other times it's an image for an advertisement etc...

I'm pretty lost right now, I have no idea how to distinguish the correct image when I display it next to it's RSS feed item. The result is inconsistency in my displayed RSS feeds, some look nice with the pictures beside the RSS item, while others have a picture of an advertisement or a picture of nothing beside them.

Would appreciate any help or a push in the right direction, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, RSS is a complex format where a lot of people can interpret things differently... A service like [Superfeedr](https://superfeedr.com) can help you by normalizing the feed's content so you don't have to look thru a dozen of different locations, but then, you'll have to do some heuristics yourself to determine what's the best image to use and if it's actually worth showing an image:
* Check its size (height, width but also surface)
* Check its entropy (colors, shapes...)
...